# CASE WHEN no me funciona SQL

Tags: sql

```
select d.cod_fac,d.montante,'' as prasa
from documento d 
left join remesa r on r.id = d.remesa_id 
left join envio_remesa er on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
case when d.cod_fac=2 then prasa='I'
     when d.cod_fac=1 then prasa='S'
where er.id = 3
```

He probado también esto:

```
select d.cod_fac,d.montante
case when d.cod_fac=2 then'I'
     when d.cod_fac=1 then 'S'
end as prasa
from documento d
left join remesa r on r.id = d.remesa_id 
left join envio_remesa er on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
where er.id = 3
```

Tengo esta consulta, donde "prasa" es una columna ficticia, estoy intentando hacer un if dependiendo del valor que sea d.cod_fac que se guarde en prasa I o S, pero no me vale, no estoy seguro si la sintaxis es la correcta o se podría hacer una de mejor manera

Comment: `cod_fac` es un int o es varchar, porque si es un varchar tiene que ser `case when d.cod_fac='2' then prasa='I'....` La sintaxis parece correcta. Aunque no has puesto el motor en el que estás trabajando. Si fuera incorrecta te daría una excepción. Además dispones de case when .... else .... Al utilizar else sabes que no entra porque la comparación establecida en el when no da true por tanto la sintaxis es buena, pero la condición no es la que esperas.

Comment: La segunda consulta es la que parece más apropiada para lo que buscas.

Comment: @Javifer2 cod_fac es un int, estoy usando postgresql, pero esto que estoy usando ahora mismo es sql plano. Igualmente en la segunda consulta da error, "error de sintaxis en o cerca de <<case>>"

Comment: te falta una coma después de d.montante

Comment: '`select d.cod_fac,d.montante,case when d.cod_fac=2 then'I' when d.cod_fac=1 then 'S' else 'algo no va bien' end as prasa from documento d ...` Así debería de funcionarte correctamente

Comment: @Javifer2 Ahora sí, gracias. Ponlo como respuesta para dartela como buena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al código le falta una coma antes de la columna `prasa`

Una manera de ver estos errores es formateando la consulta. Para esto existen varias herramientas. A mi personalmente me gusta [apexSQLFormater](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-refactor.aspx)... que puedes descargar directamente del enlace. Si mal no recuerdo te solicita un email (esta herramienta es para Sql Server)

```
select d.cod_fac
      ,d.montante
      ,case when d.cod_fac=2 then'I'
            when d.cod_fac=1 then 'S'
--          Else 'La comparación no es la que espero'
        end as prasa
from documento d
    left join remesa r on r.id = d.remesa_id 
    left join envio_remesa er on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
where er.id = 3;
```

Con la herramienta de formato, estableces que cada columna de una query vaya en una línea, con una coma delante. Además la misma herramienta, ya te indica cuando algo no le gusta y te ayuda a subsanarlo, pero, te deja el código SQL mucho más fácil de leer.

También ayuda, utilizar un else en los case, para cuando ocurre algo que no espero. Una vez corregido los errores de sintaxis, puede ocurrir que la expresión when no se esté cumpliendo, y no se exactamente el motivo. Con Else, puedo ver en que filas ocurre y a partir de ahí, afinar la query.